# Can I save the state of a NetBeans project so I can revert to it?

Tags: netbeans6.8

In Xcode there's a handy feature where you can save the state of a project and revert to a previous version. As a beginning-intermediateish programmer, I like this a lot--if I try something that doesn't work, I can obliterate it and easily get back to the way my code was before I changed anything.

Is there something similar in NetBeans? I know it integrates with SVN et al., but I'm working alone and am not sure I have time to learn it at this point in this semester. "Save As" is closer to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Git or SVN. Tortioise SVN is pretty easy to set up on Windows and doesn't take a long time to use, but it is slow and probably the way of the past. GIT is very quick and for a single person it is an idea solution. I host my NetBeans projects integrated with Eclipse (EGit) which is fantastic for local work.

http://michael-bien.com/mbien/entry/netbeans_git_plugin

This appears to be one of a few NetBeans plugins for Git and it should be pretty easy to run. You should get familiar with some form of version control sooner than later: they really make your life easier.

For SVN on Windows: 
http://tortoisesvn.net/

*On a side note:unless you're doing GUI building or you have a specific requirement for NetBeans I find Eclipse to be a better IDE on most levels--you should definitely check it out if you're just getting into programming, generally speaking it is just more responsive.*

Comment: addendum: if you're against version control you can always just copy the project folder, and replace it if post changes. It's poor mans version control hence I don't recommend it.